# How to handle forced android application termination while writing a file?

Tags: android, file-io

For a game application for Android, I am saving the player's information by writing it into a file. It is possible however for the application to be forcefully terminated during the actual file write, and what results is that the next time the user plays the game all his information is lost because the save file that was being written is empty. Is there any way around this? Here is how I am writing the file to storage:

```
        String data = "SAVEDATA";
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            File file = new File("file.txt");
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If the user ends the process while it is writing the file, then nothing gets written to the file and all previous save data is lost (since every save overwrites the file). What is the best method to circumvent this?

EDIT: I am not looking for another method to save my data, I definitely want to keep it as a file saved on the phone storage. I just want to know how to prevent data loss when the user ends the application's process while the save file is being written.

EDIT2: Is it a good idea to start a Service whenever the game data needs to be saved, so that even if the application is killed the service is still going on while the data is being saved, then the service can end itself after it is done saving?

Comment: I am doing it on onPause, and it works perfectly fine unless the user ends the application's process while the onPause function is being executed. If the user ends the process then the save file does not get written, but it has already been cleared so the save data is lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Android's AtomicFile which makes sure file will be written atomically by creating a backup file.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/AtomicFile.html

example:

```
    String data = "SAVEDATA";
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    AtomicFile atomicFile = new AtomicFile(file);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
           fos = atomicFile.startWrite();
           fos.write(data.getBytes());
           atomicFile.finishWrite(fos);
    }catch(IOException e){
           atomicFile.failWrite(fos);
           throw e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving strings or primitive values, you should use shared preferences instead, here is a link explaining its use:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I am saving a string but I would rather have it be an actual file that it is saved to so that the data can be transferred more easily between devices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid overwriting your old saves. Name your saves something like: **save_1**, **save_2**, **save_3**, ... **save_n** and erase old saves when they are no longer needed.

Another good idea is to auto save as soon as the user has accomplished something in the game. This minimizes the amount of time that your user's progress is held in volatile memory.

If your game code runs in an Activity you can also save in the onPause method.

If your game code runs in a background Service and the user ends your process manually from Android's Settings menu (or by using process killers), then the onDestroy method of your Service will be called, so you could save in that method.

Edit: If the problem that you are having is that your users close your app from the "App not responding" dialog the root cause is probably that you are saving on the UI thread. Try launching either an AsyncTask or an IntentService to do the saving.

Comment: I have considered your first point and that seems to be my best option right now, and it wouldn't be difficult to implement. It just doesn't seem like a good solution.

The biggest problem is not that data that is held in volatile memory is lost; it is that the entire save file is completely erased and gone so all data from previous game sessions is also gone.

Comment: I am using the onPause method to save the data, however if the process is ended the onPause method doesn't execute all the way.

I'm not sure if a background Service works differently from an Activity, but when I tried ending the process for my application (its an Activity not a Service), the onDestroy function did not get called. The onPause function does not get called either when the process is killed (unless of course the process was already paused before it was killed).

Comment: Yeah, if the save takes a long time you should not do it on the UI thread. See AsyncTask and IntentService for two different ways to do a task on a separate thread.

Comment: An IntentService and AsyncTask will both be killed at the same time the actual process is killed, so it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That is true, but under normal circumstances the process will not get killed. How and why is the process killed?

Comment: A lot of people like to kill all the running apps on their device, especially on some devices that make it very easy for them to kill the running apps, for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqv_q5rGAfQ

I myself have a habit to do that a lot and close the running apps on my phone, but unfortunately this messes up with the saving process. If I start a service and the user does that like in the video above, will the service also be stopped? Or is the service only stopped by the "Force Stop" button in settings?

Comment: Using multiple files is a good idea, but you cannot count on getting a destroy notification - in fact you **will not** if the process is simply killed at the operating system, rather than android level.

Answer (score -1):

Saving your data in [`onPause`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) is the way to go; Further reading below for [data storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

1. [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
2. [Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
3. [Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
4. [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Further reading [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) for basic data storage

hope it helps :)

Comment: I am currently using the onPause function to save my data. However, if the user ends the process while the onPause function is running then it stops execution in the middle and causes the save file to become corrupt because the file that it was overwriting was already cleared, but the new data was not added yet. I am able to reproduce this very easily on my Galaxy S3 phone since I am saving a rather large save file that takes a reasonable amount of time to be completely written.

Comment: ok,
i guess the way to go around is create a service. 
Start it `onPause` on a different process which will be killed use `stopSelf` to kill it after saving the data.